# Setting the Hour and Minute of Timepicker dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timepicker

I am dynamically adding [Timepickers](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/) to my webpage. Once I have loaded all of the html, or basically did [jquery.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
<div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
   <input class="form-control timepicker"id="timepicker-default" type="text">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
           <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
        </span>
    </input>
</div>
```

and then:

```
$('.timepicker').each(function(){
    $(this).timepicker();
});
```

to bind them to the timepicker.js file in my website.

My problem is that I want to be able to set the time while doing the above for-each function. I am using [Parse.com](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide) as my backend so the date comes in as "Tue Sep 01 2015 13:15:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)". I want to be able to extract the time from the one I just mentioned then set the hour and minute of the timepicker its currently on. I know the logic of cycling through each one, but I don't know how to set the individual timepicker.

I tried to get an example running for you in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkv7z7h4/4) but couldn't get it to load it right.

P.S. I know the for-each function is working because I have tested it.

Comment: here is an update to your fiddle the js is fixed but you need to add the correct urls to the timepicker js and css as its not finding them http://jsfiddle.net/xkv7z7h4/1/ If you do that I may look into your issue further

Comment: updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xkv7z7h4/4/

Comment: thanks @EdenSource for updating it to the correct URLs, I will update the question.

Comment: Read the docs and http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/ search the section **Set Time Example**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create a `Date` object depending on the way you get your date string:

```
var d = new Date("Tue Sep 01 2015 13:15:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)");
$(this).timepicker('setTime', d);
```

And it finally looks like:

```
$('.timepicker').each(function(){
    $(this).timepicker();
    var d = new Date("Tue Sep 01 2015 13:15:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)");
    $(this).timepicker('setTime', d);
});
```

See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dkogyurz/)

Comment: I literally just figured it out as you posted this answer XD but I will mark it as best. Mosh Feu was partially correct but the documentation only account for "new Date()" and not setting a predefined date object. I had to read through some other documentation in order to set the hours and minutes or else he would've been correct immediately. Thanks EdenSource!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to EdenSource's answer but doesn't use `.each()`

Rather it sets the time on the individual input when appending it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#adder").click(function () {
       var html = '<div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker" style="padding-bottom:10px;">' + '<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span></div>';

        $("#timepickerDiv").append(html);

        $('<input class="form-control timepicker" type="text">')
            .prependTo($('.bootstrap-timepicker:last'))
            .timepicker() .timepicker('setTime', new Date());


    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0txqe7LL/)**